# Understanding and Proving Continuity of a Function in a Broad Sense

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

At the moment I am studying a chapter about Sobolev spaces in a book on partial differential equations authored by Evans. I have a question about continuity of a function in a broad sense. More specifically how to show that a given function is continuous. A function could be continuous in different ways. Such as *Holder*, *Lipschitz* or *uniform* continuous. We could also define a function as being continuous in a *weak* or *strong* sense.

I am aware of the basic definition of continuity. A small change in the input should lead to a small change in the output. No jumps should occur in a graph of a function. I know a little why it is important. For instance: Picard-Lindelof theorem.

I asked my self how I could know that a function is continuous or not was by just plotting it in a plotting tool and evaluate the graph. No jumps in the graph means that it is continuous. However, if I would do this this would lead to a few confusions. Such as how can I see that it is Holder or Lipschitz continous? What is the Lipschitz constant? If this would work so well why do we need use a weak formulation any way? Why do we just not put the non-weak formulated function in a program, plot it and make our conclusions?

About what I said about weak formulation. I do know why we use a weak formulation (according to the explanation of Wikipedia and the book that I described earlier). However, I am unable to connect all the dots.

*EDIT*: I am also aware of the epsilon-delta definition.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to answer my question partially. I think from here I could develop further my knowledge further. Weak formulation and Holder continuity are described in the book that I described in my earlier post. How they work is not needed for know. Proving how a function is continuous has to do with how a series of a function converges.